# Can't Archive iOS application build in Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, archive

My Application is created in Flutter, it was built successfully. but when I tried to Upload in Appstore facing this issue.

I am attaching a screenshot of the error.

[image: A]

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39864 See if this is helpful!!

Comment: Thanks , Yeah ! i got solution from here https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios#create-a-build-archive